# Restrict form field choices based on previous model choice in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am currently attempting to create a DnD 5e Character creator using Django and SRD materials provided by WoTC. This is the first time I have ever used Django, and I am learning it as I go. I have come up against a bit of a challenge that has stone-walled me for a few days now. I have researched the issue, and after applying multiple techniques I thought may help, I've had limited luck. My question is this:

I have a number of models representing Heroes, Races, Subraces, Classes, Backgrounds and so forth. I wish to be able to restrict a users ability to choose a Subrace, based on their selection of a race beforehand.
So far I have this:

### models.py

```
class Race(models.Model):
    race_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    race_size = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=SIZE_CHOICE, default='M')
    race_speed = models.IntegerField(
        default=30)
    race_lang = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    race_str = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    race_dex = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    race_con = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    race_int = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    race_wis = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    race_cha = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    skill_spend = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    race_extra = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    race_source = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.race_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Race'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Races'


class Subrace(models.Model):
    sub_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_size = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=SIZE_CHOICE, default='M', null=True)
    sub_speed = models.IntegerField(
        default=30, null=True)
    sub_lang = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_str = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_dex = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_con = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_int = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_wis = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_cha = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_extra = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_parent = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sub_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Subrace'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Subraces'

class Hero(models.Model):

    def roll_stats():
        d6 = die.Dice(6)
        list_stats = d6.roll(4)
        list_stats.sort()
        add = sum(list_stats[1:4])
        return add

    hero_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    hero_subrace = models.ForeignKey(
        Subrace, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', blank=True, null=True)
    hero_klass = models.ForeignKey(Klass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    hero_race = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    background = models.ForeignKey(
        Background, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    health = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    hero_exp = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    hero_alignment = models.ForeignKey(Alignment, blank=True, null=True)
    hero_str = models.IntegerField(default=roll_stats, null=True, blank=True)
    hero_dex = models.IntegerField(default=roll_stats, null=True, blank=True)
    hero_con = models.IntegerField(default=roll_stats, null=True, blank=True)
    hero_int = models.IntegerField(default=roll_stats, null=True, blank=True)
    hero_wis = models.IntegerField(default=roll_stats, null=True, blank=True)
    hero_cha = models.IntegerField(default=roll_stats, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        "Returns a hero's hp"
        die_str = str(self.hero_klass.hit_dice)
        die_nums = die_str.split("d")
        die_val = int(die_nums[1])
        die_roll = int(die_nums[0])
        hp_die = die.Dice(die_val)
        results = hp_die.roll(die_roll)
        self.health = sum(results)
        super(Hero, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hero_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('hero.views.detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Hero'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Heroes'
```

### views.py

```
def new_hero(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = HeroForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            hero = form.save(commit=False)
            hero.author = request.user
            hero.save()
            return redirect('detail', hero.pk)
    else:
        form = HeroForm()
    return render(request, 'new_hero.html', {'form': form, 'user': user})
```

### forms.py

```
class HeroForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = ['hero_name', 'hero_race', 'hero_subrace',
                  'hero_klass', 'hero_exp', 'health', 'background',
                  'hero_str', 'hero_dex', 'hero_con', 'hero_int',
                  'hero_wis', 'hero_cha', 'hero_alignment']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HeroForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for fieldname in ['hero_str', 'hero_dex', 'hero_con', 'hero_int', 'hero_wis', 'hero_cha']:
            self.fields[fieldname].disabled = True
        race = Race.objects.all()
        for name in race:
            self.fields['hero_subrace'].queryset = Subrace.objects.filter(sub_parent=name)
```

I have trialled a few different techniques, but this is where I am now. This:

```
for name in race:
            self.fields['hero_subrace'].queryset = Subrace.objects.filter(sub_parent=name)
```

is my most recent addition to my app. At the hero creation screen I am hit with a blank box of choices, as opposed to the full unrestricted list without the loop or queryset.

Basically I'm hoping that someone has some advice for me on a method I may be overlooking, or something that I've missed, or simply not found yet. Also please feel free to critique the rest of the code, like I said this is my first Django App :). Also my first Stack Overflow question, so thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that is wondering, I used [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) to solve my problem.

### base.html

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/bindfields.js' %}"></script>
```

I added the above html to my `{% load staticfiles %}` call.

and changed models.py:

### models.py

```python
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey
class Hero(models.Model):
    ....
    race = models.ForeignKey(Race, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subrace = ChainedForeignKey(Subrace,
                                chained_field="race",
                                chained_model_field="race",
                                show_all=False,
                                auto_choose=True,
                                blank=True,
                                null=True)
```

Now I have a subrace field that is dynamically update when the user chooses a Race.